# Create Enum from XML at compile time

Tags: java, xml, enums, compile-time

That´s all, I need to create an Enum whose values or labels are stored in XML file. XML won´t be modified at runtime. I want to let the user specify the values for a given attribute (for example, available colors for the attribute Colour of the Car class). I am planning to use an Interface so I can code the rest of the application, and then generate Enums implementing that interface.

---

Solution: I have decided to use a collection, implementing methods to avoid duplicated values.

Comment: Enums were supposed to be static constants and you want to create them dynamically? Why?

Comment: Because the user might want to add a new label to the Enum type in the future (for example a new colour available).

Comment: but enums are defined at compilation time, while reading a XML is something that happens at execution time. why don't you use a dynamic structure such as a regular java object for that? Looks to me that you're trying to do something in the worst way

Comment: I will use a collection without duplicated values, this way I can add/remove values

Comment: You can use a Model Driven Architecture approach, using a maven module to generate Java Enums from your XML by using for instance AndroMDA.